# Extracting values in a timeseries data and calculate the tie duration

Tags: python, pandas

Problem statement:
There are multiple instances of charging and discharging for each vehicle column_name= 'soc', from this column get two new df (ref Required output) get minimum SOC, maximum SOC for charging cycle each vehicle and similarly get min SoC  and max SoC for every discharge cycle and time duration(discharge) for each vehicle for a particular day to a new df

```
df1
Date             Time    vehicle_no  soc     SOC Diff
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    0
1   2022-10-01  02:28:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56    DL21GD0100  69.0    Discharging
5    2022-10-01 02:29:56    DL21GD0100  70.0    Charging
6    2022-10-01 02:30:56    DL21GD0100  71.0    Charging
7    2022-10-01 02:32:56    DL21GD0100  72.0    Charging
8   2022-10-01 03:16:00    DL21GD0100   63.0    Discharging
9  2022-10-01  04:16:30    DL21GD0100    23.0    Discharging
10 2022-10-01  04:16:30    DL21GD0100    24.0    Charging
11 2022-10-01  04:17:00    DL21GD0100    54.0    Charging
12  2022-10-01  09:17:30    WB25M9298   24.0    Charging
13 2022-10-01  10:21:00    WB25M9298   57.0    Charging
```

```
Required output

Charging
  Date         Vehicle_no Min_Soc Max_SOC Time_Dur    Total 
                                          (hh:mm:ss)   Consumed_Soc
2022-10-01   DL21GD0100    70.0     72.0     00:03:00     23.0
2022-10-01  DL21GD0100      23.0    54.0     01:01:00     21.0
2022-10-01  WB25M9298     24.0       57.0  01:03:30      33.0
```

```
Discharging
SL.No  Date   Vehicle_no  Max_Soc Max_SOC   Time_dur    Total
                                           (hh:mm:ss)  Soc_Disch
1   2022-10-01  DL21GD0100  80.0  69.0    00:02:00      11.0
2   2022-10-01  DL21GD0100  63.0  23.0     01:00:00     40.0
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, programming problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement:

There are multiple instances of charging and discharging for each vehicle Column_name='soc',from this column get a two new df(Ref- Required output) where minimum SOC, maximum SOC for a particular vehicle where the status= Charging .Similarly fetch min SOC and max SOC and time duration(Discharge)  for each vehicle for a particular day.

```
df1
Date             Time    vehicle_no  soc     SOC Diff
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    0
1   2022-10-01  02:28:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56    DL21GD0100  69.0    Discharging
5    2022-10-01 02:29:56    DL21GD0100  70.0    Charging
6    2022-10-01 02:30:56    DL21GD0100  71.0    Charging
7    2022-10-01 02:32:56    DL21GD0100  72.0    Charging
8   2022-10-01 03:16:00    DL21GD0100   63.0    Discharging
9  2022-10-01  04:16:30    DL21GD0100    23.0    Discharging
10  2022-10-01  04:17:00    DL21GD0100    54.0    Charging
11  2022-10-01  09:17:30    WB25M9298   24.0    Charging
12  2022-10-01  10:21:00    WB25M9298   57.0    Charging
```

```
Tried this 
#From the Soc Data identify the Min and Max Soc 

#Set your range
range_min=0
range_max=100

#define the functions to be applied
#evaluate if soc is low

def eval_low(soc):
    if soc <= range_min:
        return soc
    else:
        return 0
#evaluate if soc is high   
def eval_high(soc):
    if soc >= range_max:
        return soc
    else:
        return 0
    
    
#evaluate the functions in a new column
df2['Min_soc']=df2.soc.apply(eval_low)
df2['Max_soc']=df2.soc.apply(eval_high)
    
Doesn't serve the purpose
```

```
Required output


Charging
  Date         Vehicle_no Min_Soc Max_SOC Time_Dur    Total 
                                          (hh:mm:ss)   Consumed_Soc
2022-10-01   DL21GD0100    70.0     72.0     00:03:00     23.0
2022-10-01  DL21GD0100      23.0    54.0     01:01:00     21.0
2022-10-01  WB25M9298     24.0       57.0  01:03:30      33.0
Where Time Duration for charging= time at Max_Soc- time at Min_SOC
```

```
Discharging
SL.No  Date   Vehicle_no  Max_Soc Max_SOC   Time_dur    Total
                                           (hh:mm:ss)  Soc_Disch
1   2022-10-01  DL21GD0100  80.0  69.0    00:02:00      11.0
2   2022-10-01  DL21GD0100  63.0  23.0     01:00:00     40.0
Where Time Duration for discharging= time at Max_Soc- time at Min_SOC
```